# dotenv in Folder Build

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I have an .env in my React js project, I want when I NPM run build the .env goes to the build folder is that possible? If yes, how do I do it if not what is the solution?

i have tried using

"build": "cp .env.template build/.env && react-scripts build"

but the result is that dotenv cannot enter the build folder

Comment: What do you mean with "cannot enter the build folder", are you getting an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a separate config.js file in your project's
   directory with your environment variables.

> ```
> const config = {
>   API_URL: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL,
> }
>
> export default config;
> ```

2. import the config.js file into react components and access the
   environment variables.

> ```
> import React from 'react';
>
> import config from './config';
>
> function App() {
>   const apiUrl = config.API_URL;
>
>   return <div>...</div>;
> }
> export default App;
> ```

3. Create a custom build script, for example, build.js, in your
   project's root directory.

> ```
> const fs = require('fs');
> const path = require('path');
> const { execSync } = require('child_process');
>
> // Copy the config.js file to the build folder
> fs.copyFileSync(
>   path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'config.js'),
>   path.resolve(__dirname, 'build', 'config.js')
> );
>
> // Run the build script
> execSync('react-scripts build', { stdio: 'inherit' });
> ```

4. Modify your package.json file to use the custom build script

> ```
> "scripts": {
>   "build": "node build.js"
> }
> ```

Comment: thank you, it works fine, but when I do "npm run build" the files are copied but immediately deleted, why?